Why is Shan'auc's mark in gold?
We know Jaffa wear the mark of their master/god on their foreheads; typically a black tattoo, except the "first prime" whose mark is raised gold.
In the SG-1 episode "Crossroads", Shan'auc wears the sign of Apophis, like Teal'c, but hers is also gold like Teal'c (albeit hers is flat), even though she is not "first prime".

Is this an indication that she is a high (highest?) priestess, or something?

Fro'tak has a silver mark. Gold and silver seem to denote importance, not necessarily First Prime-hood

Note that hers is flat, not raised.
